# Adding a date filter to a view in drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

I am using views api to show a certain list of nodes. Now I want to add a date filter such that it helps to filter nodes that are created between a start date and end date. My date should contain the time information as well to refine it more. How can I accomplish this? Basically, I want to expose a date filter start and end date that will filter the nodes displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add "Node revision: created date" as filter and can expose the filter. so that the filter will appear in the front end, using that we can display the nodes that are created between two given dates.